# MPI isend, confirmation of delivery

Tags: c++, mpi

I have written a simple send/recv between two processes.  I use `isend` and `irecv` to pass a message.

On the sender side, I capture the `mpi::request` object returned by the `isend` and use it to verify the message is delivered.  However, it appears that the confirmation (ie. `request.test()`) returns a valid `status` object (with `status->error == 0`) long before the `irecv` is actually executed on the receiver (I have a sleep(20) prior to the `irecv`).  From this do i conclude that the status is an indication of delivery (to the queue) and not an indication that the message was read ?

Perhaps worth mentioning I am using boost::mpi, C++ on Ubuntu.

Comment: That's right.  The send associated with the request being completed means just that - the _send_ is completed.  What the receiver has or hasn't done with it is a (somewhat) separate question.

Comment: @Jonathan Dursi Thanks for the confirmation... is isend/irecv (and checking the status of the isend) considered an acceptable level of message delivery verification ? (as opposed to blocking send/recv) ?  Essentially does the blocking form of send provide any additional confirmation that the message was delivered *and* recv'd ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  MPI guarantees that all successfully sent messages get to their recipient, and in fact guarantees something about their order, so once it's successfully sent - from a blocking send, or once the status is successful from a nonblocking send - it will eventually be available for receiving.  Having said that, you should always check the request statuses of all non-blocking communications (with test(), or wait(), or some such) for a variety of reasons - both the isend and the irecv.

Comment: @Jonathan Dursi Thank you for the response and great info, very much appreciated !